# AlarmManager and WakeLock example

Tags: android

I tried this wakefull example:https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Wakeful

But I have a few questions.

Do I need `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />`? because the intent is always null, as I tested.

And inScheduledService is:

```
@Override
    protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "I ran!");
    }
```

But this method is never fired.

In WakefulintentService there is this method, which is also never fired:

```
 @Override
    final protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            doWakefulWork(intent);
        } finally {
            PowerManager.WakeLock lock = getLock(this.getApplicationContext());

            if (lock.isHeld()) {
                lock.release();
            }
        }
    }
```

What to change, so that i will get `I ran` as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need ?

Only if you wish to set up your alarms again after a reboot. By default, alarms are wiped out when the device reboots.

> but this method is never fired.

Yes, it is. You can tell this by running the project.

> in WakefulintentService is this method which is also never fired:

Yes, it is. You can tell this by running the project.

For example, here is the output of a run I just did now:

```
12-11 14:03:05.671: D/ScheduledService(3322): I ran!
12-11 14:03:10.671: D/ScheduledService(3322): I ran!
12-11 14:03:15.671: D/ScheduledService(3322): I ran!
12-11 14:03:20.671: D/ScheduledService(3322): I ran!
```